# Xcode 6-Running app on device crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, crash

When I run my app on the simulator, it works fine. However, when I run it on my iPhone the app will work fine but sometimes it will pause and crash? How can I fix this issue? Where can I go to diagnose the problem?

I included images in the background of the main page that transition. I used Instruments and under Allocations->Category it is using a lot of memory from PNG_Data. I simply include about twelve .png photos in my Xcode project. Below is the code where the images are used.

```
extension Array {
func shuffled() -> [T] {
    var list = self
    for i in 0..<(list.count - 1) {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(list.count - i))) + i
        swap(&list[i], &list[j])
    }
    return list
}
}

import Foundation

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

@IBAction func unwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}   
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

// Array of images
let images = [
    UIImage(named: "nature1@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "nature2@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "desk2@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york8@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york9@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york10@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york11@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york14@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york15@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "rainy_window1@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "rainy_window2@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york16@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york17@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "wall_st2@2x.png")!]

// Setting durations and intervals for transitions
var index = 0
let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 1.5
let switchingInterval: NSTimeInterval = 4


// VIEW DID LOAD
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = images[index++]
    animateImageView()


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: {()-> Void in
        self.logo.alpha = 1.0})
}

// Function that animates the background
func animateImageView() {
    CATransaction.begin()

    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration) // passing in animationDuration
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(self.switchingInterval * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.animateImageView()
        }
    }

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade // the type of transition

    var new_images = images.shuffled() // SHUFFLING the images array

    imageView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    imageView.image = new_images[index]

    CATransaction.commit()

    index = index < images.count - 1 ? index + 1 : 0
}
```

Comment: You have to add the error and where it appears in the code. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: In the console it simply says "Received memory warning."

Comment: Added the code above. Not sure why the images are using so much memory. Should I place the folder of images somewhere else? I simply have them in my Xcode project. Is my code not efficient, when utilizing the images?

Comment: Do you have all i.ages included?  Sometimes the simulator creates big cache and reload the image from there.

Comment: Do the images need to be in the assets catalog or can they be in a folder in my Xcode project?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really silly thing to do:

```
let images = [
    UIImage(named: "nature1@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "nature2@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "desk2@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york8@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york9@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york10@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york11@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york14@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york15@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "rainy_window1@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "rainy_window2@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york16@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "new_york17@2x.png")!,
    UIImage(named: "wall_st2@2x.png")!]
```

Basically you are saying, "Load all these images and hold on to them all simultaneously." Images are *huge*, so naturally you are running out of memory.

It's fine to make an array of image *names*, because names are just tiny little strings; so why not do that? Then load one only when you actually need it, to show it in the interface.

Comment: How would I do this by just calling the image names? In my code in the original post, I have the array and I iterate through it. Aren't the images getting cached? I am confused as to how to go about this to avoid using so much memory.

Comment: iterate the names, load then and only then, that one image.  Retain no images.

Comment: How do I not retain any images? In my animateImageView function, I have imageView.image = new_images[index]. I do not know how to avoid retaining images as it iterates through the array of strings?

Comment: Yes, but then on the next iteration you will say that again - thus releasing the image that was previously there! Thus you will retain only one image at a time. There is a _huge_ difference between that and retaining 14 images at once. - Moreover it will not be you that is retaining it; it will be retained because it is actually being _used_ (it's being shown in the interface).

Comment: Also make sure your images are no bigger than needed for display. The waste of memory in displaying an image that is larger than needed is immense.

Comment: Ok. My images are bigger than they should be so I will reduce their size. I am confused as to what you mean by call it again. I have this simple for loop. I am not sure how it is preventing image retention.                                            for (var i = 0; i < images.count; i++){
 
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: new_images[i])
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: new_images[i])
    }

Comment: And that's what I mean. Think about it. Each time thru the loop, you say `imageView.image = UIImage(named: new_images[i])`. So how many images are there now? Just one! No matter how many times you go thru the loop, `imageView.image` is at most just one image. How could it be more???? So there _is_ only one image in existence at any given moment. That's hugely different than ... but now you are making me repeat myself.